# How can this code be improved with java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to find if there are any Users over the age of 18 in the given list. If there is no user over age 18, the method should return -1. Otherwise, it should return the age of the youngest user.

While using the streams, I created the following method, however, the stream is used twice. Is there a better way to do this with streams

```
public int test(List<User> userList) {
    List<User> usersOver18 = userList.stream()
            .filter(emp -> emp.getAge() > 18)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (usersOver18.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return usersOver18.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge))
            .get().getAge();
}
```

Comment: Apart from chaining the stream instead of `collect`ing it, you can also map to age and avoid unchecked `.get` such as `return userList.stream()
                .filter(emp -> emp.getAge() > 18)
                .mapToInt(User::getAge)
                .min()
                .orElse(-1);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can map to the age, filter out anything 18 or under, and then return the minimum or -1 if the stream is empty:

```
public int test(List<User> userList) {
    return userList.stream()
        .mapToInt(User::getAge)
        .filter(age -> age > 18)
        .min().orElse(-1);
}
```

Note that after `mapToInt()`, you are working with an `IntStream` and not `Stream<Integer>`, and `min()` returns `OptionalInt`, not `Optional<Integer>`.

By the way, are you sure the age filter is not `>= 18`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing this from memory on my phone so it might not be perfect, but...

```
return userList
    .stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getAge() > 18)
    .min(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge))
    .map(User::getAge)
    .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: It would be better to map to age first instead of always referring to the age via the user.